# Apple has ditched matte laptop displays: Display replacement options?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I was thinking about buying a MacBook Pro for coding while not at home, but suddenly realized that they all come with **glossy** displays. The glare/mirror effect is utterly unacceptable for me. Are there good and easy ways to fix this?

By *good* I mean:

- No voiding of warranty
- No other nasty visual side-effects (apart from slightly reducing overall brightness, which is OK)
- No noticeable additional weight

By *easy* I mean, either somebody else would install it, or it may be installed by a very silly guy like me with near-zero probability of breaking anything. :)

Comment: For what it is worth: I'd recommend using it for a bit before installing something that isn't easy to remove. I was of your opinion before I got my latest computer, very upset that I couldn't get a matte display, and about a week in it didn't bother me at all.

Comment: I ended up not being bothered by reflections, looks like MBP with Retina has very good glass on the display. :)

Comment: @SargeBorsch Yeah. Normally I hate glossy monitors and get dizzy for staring too long. but Retina display doesn't feel like it's glossy at all. It's totally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple sells an [Anti-glare filter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/HC223ZM/A/3m-13-privacy-anti-glare-filter-for-macbook-pro-with-retina-display?fnode=53) on the online Apple Store.

An alternative is the [Moshi iVisor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009J90R4W) which you can find on Amazon.